# How to validate a single field in Blazor EditForm?

Tags: c#, blazor, data-annotations, blazor-server-side, blazor-client-side

I'm getting the `EditContext` from `CascadingParameter`

```
[CascadingParameter]
public EditContext EditContext { get; set; }
```

And I realized that exists a `.Validate` method, that validates the entire `Model` of `EditForm`.

But I want to validate only one field of the `Model`.

Who can I validate only one field of the `Model` from `EditForm`?

If you are wondering why I want this... Is because I'm making a custom component that when the value changes and it's a valid value, it will do something.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While looking at [Peter Morris Library](https://github.com/mrpmorris/blazor-validation), I found out that if you want to validate non complex fields, you only need to create a `FieldIdentifier` and call `EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier)` and it will trigger that field validation.

So the answer is much more simple:

```
// Get the FieldIdentifier with the EditContext from the field name
FieldIdentifier fieldIdentifier = EditContext.Field(fieldName);

// Validate the field when notifying change
EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(fieldIdentifier);

// To check if the field is valid, 
// check if there is any error message. 
return !EditContext.GetValidationMessages(fieldIdentifier).Any();
```

Comment: You need reflection if you want to preserve the modified state.

Comment: It's possible to validate a complex object without reflection?

Comment: If you don't want to create a new isntance of `FieldIdentifier` there is also the `EditContext.Field(string fieldName)` method you can call to get the `FieldIdentifier`. For example you could write it as `EditContext.NotifyFieldChanged(EditContext.Field(fieldName));`